# Socket Connection Refused [Errno 111]

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to implement a simple ftp with sockets using C (server side) and Python (client side). When the server code is compiled and run, the user enters a port number. The client then enters "localhost " when compiling. For some reason I am getting [Errno 111] on the client side when I run the code. It is saying that the issue is with my `client.connect` statement. I have tried using multiple different port numbers and it throws this same error:

```
flip1 ~/FTPClient 54% python ftpclientNew.py localhost 2500
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftpclientNew.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "ftpclientNew.py", line 27, in main
    if client.connect((serverName, portNumber)) == None:
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Another weird thing is that this connection error was not happening when I ran this same code a few days ago. Has anyone experienced a problem like this? Any idea what might be causing this? Thanks!

Here is the client code:

```
import sys, posix, string
from socket import *

def main():

    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print "\nFormat: 'localhost' <port number>!\n"
        return 0

    buffer = ""
    bufferSize = 500
    serverName = "localhost"
    fileBuffer = [10000]

    if sys.argv[1] != serverName: 
        print "Incorrect Server Name! \n"
        return 0

    portNumber = int(sys.argv[2])

    client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    if client < 0:
        print "Error Creating Socket!! \n"
        return 0

    if client.connect((serverName, portNumber)) == None:
        print "Client Socket Created...\n"
        print "Connecting to the server...\n"
        print "Connected!\n"
        ##clientName = raw_input("Enter a file name: ")
```

Comment: Ensure that port is opened with `netstat`, try another client or server, debug with `nc` and `tcpdump`.

Comment: 111 means there was no server listening on the port or the server actively rejected the connection. That second one would only be true if you server sets the "linger" option which it likely doesn't. Is this linux/mac? Its been suggested that you look at what ports are open with `netstat`. That's a good idea. Your code is a little bizzare (it requires that you enter a host name but errors if its not 'localhost') but should work. Its the server side that's a problem. You could add `print gethostbyname('localhost')` to make sure you don't have a system configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes localhost isn't working on host

Change this

```
serverName = 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the `serverName` variable to `127.0.0.1`.